# Stripe: add a one off payment to a subscription

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

Is it possible in Stripe to add a one off payment to a subscription, without creating a dedicated plan?

For example, if I had an apple subscription business where we charge £4 per month to receive a bag of apples, and wanted to offer users the chance to add a couple of bananas in January.

Except, as well as bananas you could add almost any number of any other type of fruit, then the following month go straight back to being signed up for your bag of apples.

I could charge the card the difference, but with the subscription going out on a set day each month and it might make for a messy bank statement. I'm using Laravel with Cashier at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the invoice item object for this purpose. The invoice item can be added to a subscription and would be payed during the next subscription billing cycle.

Alternatively you can also just create a charge a la carte. This would have nothing to do with the subscription directly, and simply charged the card for the purchase.

Invoice Item:
https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_invoiceitem

Charge:
https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge