# Laravel cashier - add invoice item to subscription

Tags: php, laravel-5, stripe-payments

I'm using `Laravel's` `Stripe integration` to bill customers on a monthly basis.

Is it possible to add an **invoice item** to my subscription, so that my customer is billed monthly for a number of items he/she used within that period?

[This question suggests that it is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26907695/stripe-add-a-one-off-payment-to-a-subscription?rq=1)

And `Laravel's` documentation covers [creating an invoice](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/billing#chargewithinvoice) but not adding an invoice item.

Does anyone know if there is a `Laravel` method for **add invoice item**? If not, how is an invoice item added?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but since I didn't find an answer anywhere I'll share what I found:

When creating a new subscription with cashier you can pass in additional options for the subscription.
The parameter of interest is "add_invoice_items" which lets you tack one-off payments onto the 1st invoice of a subscription.

```
$user->newSubscription('default', 'basic')
    ->create($paymentMethod, [
        'name' => 'customer name',
        // other customer data
    ],[
       'add_invoice_items' => [
          [
             'price' => 'your_stripe_price_id',
             'quantity' => 1
          ]
      ],
      // Any other subscription ot
]);
```

To see subscription options  https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create
To see custoemr options https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create

Answer (score 1):

I think will be easier with Laravel 5.4, but since it's not out as of this writing, you have to set it up manually.

with Laravel 5.4 (assuming this function makes it in)

```
$user->invoiceForUpcoming('One-time charge', 1000);
```

Manual way (make sure you have Cashier installed, etc):

```
use Stripe\InvoiceItem as StripeInvoiceItem;
```

The in your controller or wherever makes sense:

```
$options = [
  'customer' => $user->stripe_id,
  'amount' => 1000,
  'currency' => 'usd',
  'description' => 'One-time fee',
];
$response = StripeInvoiceItem::create(
  $options, ['api_key' => config('services.stripe.secret')]
);
```

Comment: For anyone looking the function did make it in but with a different name. $user->tab('One-time charge', 1000);