# How to charge customer using Laravel Cashier one time and then charge monthly after some time?

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I am building a payment system where a customer can join the system using some upfront charge let's say 10$. That amount would be for let says 3 months. And after that, I want to charge them monthly for their extended duration. I am using Laravel Cashier.
So should I first charge the customer using the normal payment charge, and then add a trial subscription of let says 3 months and after that charge customer based on the date? Or is there any other approach?
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with Laravel Cashier, but usually what you can do is create a subscription with a 3 months trial period and use the `add_invoice_items`[[0]](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-add_invoice_items) to add the upfront one-off charge.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63709897/8097655 like this link?

Comment: yes exactly like that.